# Windows 11 - Touchpad movement feels sloppy and too smooth, not sharp

Tags: touchpad, windows-11, cursor

I recently upgraded my Acer Aspire 3 (Ryzen 5 3500U) laptop from Windows 10 to 11.

In Windows 11 the touchpad doesn't feel the same as before, I notice some sort of lag in the movement of the cursor, and also feels too smooth. In Windows 10, the cursor movement was sharp and fast, and now it feels sloppy. This doesn't happen with mouse tough.
I have tried to disable pointer precision for the trackpad but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, Finally people care about this issue. I have been facing this same issue my touchpad just randomly slows down and then after a restart or some time it revert back to normal i surely know its not because of trackpad dirt because i checked the trackpad clearly and i just bought my laptop a couple months ago.. mine is a rtx 3080 laptop with 32 gb.. just hate when this happens and still happens as i am writing this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1143760)

Answer (score 0):

Finally someone noticed it too. I tried every settings available, but it is still slow and too smooth with a little lag. The weird thing is it's not always like than. It'll just randomly slow down and then a few minutes it will revert back to normal. Tried cleaning the trackpad side too maybe it's the dust and dirt but no luck. I have a ryzen 4600H and 16 GB ram so I don't think it has to do with performance. It's just annoying cause pointing is so hard and becomes in accurate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1124842)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this strange stuttering and lagging of the mouse cursor and using a trackpad on a new Win11 Laptop.

Disabling the mouse pointer trail did the trick!

[image]

may be there is some subtil hesistation in scrolling left...
and also curious to know what is happening under the hoods.